# Lookup function not working in Visualforce Page after reRender of apex:repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a strange issue in vf page,I have attached my code below.Onclicking remove service particular page block is getting removed and the record also getting removed from database.But onclicking  remove service button the lookup functionality in the last page block is not working.I couldnt figure out the issue its seems to be strange.

```
<apex:sectionHeader Title="product"  />

<div style="float:right; padding-top:25px">
        <apex:commandButton value="Add Service" action="{!Add}" immediate="true" reRender="addservicereRender"/>
 </div>             

    <apex:outputPanel id="addservicereRender" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!prod}" var="p" id="theRepeat">            
    <apex:pageBlock id="block1">

    <div>
        <apex:outputLabel value="productlookup"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <apex:inputField value="{!p.product__c}" onFocus="this.blur()"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Remove Service" action="{!Remove}" style="float:right" reRender="addservicereRender" immediate="true">
            <apex:param name="PId" value="{!p.Id}" />  
        </apex:commandButton>
    </div> 

    <apex:pageBlockSection id="section1">               

                <apex:inputfield value="{!p.prdouct1}" />


                <apex:inputField value="{!p.prdouct2}"  />


                <apex:inputField value="{!p.prdouct3}"  />

 </apex:pageBlockSection> 


</apex:pageBlock>       
</apex:repeat> 
</apex:outputPanel> 

</apex:form>
```

```
public with sharing class example1Controller {


public LIst<example__c> prod {get;set;}
public String OpportunityId{get;set;}

public example1Controller() 
{
    try{
        OpportunityId =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        prod = new list<example__c>();
        String Action  =ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('action');


        if(OpportunityId != null && OpportunityId != '') 
        {
            prod =  [SELECT Id,product__c,prdouct1__c,prdouct2__c,prdouct3__c FROM example__c WHERE Opportunity__c =:OpportunityId];

            if(Action == 'add'){
                example__c  e = new example__c();
                e.Opportunity__c = OpportunityId;
                prod.add(e);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
    } 
}




public void Add()
{
    try{
       example__c  e = new example__c();
       e.Opportunity__c = OpportunityId;
       prod.add(e);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
    } 
}

//************** RemoveService *****************************//
public void Remove()
{
    try{

        boolean hasRun = false;
        String exampleId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('PId');
        System.debug('exampleId:'+exampleId );
        if (exampleId != null && exampleId != '') 
        {
            example__c s;
            for(example__c sl: prod )
            {
                if(sl.Id == exampleId)
                {

                    s = Sl;
                }
            } 
            delete s;
            for(Integer i=0;i<prod.size();i++)
            {
                if(prod[i].Id==exampleId)
                {
                    prod.remove(i);

                }
            }                                     
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

}

[image]

Onclicking remove service pageblock is removed but the lookup in last pageblock is not working.

[image]

Comment: n.b. you're overloading the page param 'ID' to be both the Oppo Id and the line item to be removed product Id. This is confusing and you might want to use 'PID' for the name of the param in the latter case

Comment: What error you are getting when you click on lookup? Check the error on web console.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "the last page block is not working". Can you describe that a bit more detailed?

Also, why are you using the onfocus event on your lookup field and why on earth is this calling "this.blur()" ?

Comment: The error on the console is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null VM1109:1
(anonymous function)

Comment: And the contents of VM1109 is  openLookup('/_ui/common/data/LookupPage?lkfm=j_id0%3Anewform&lknm=j_id0%3Anewform%3AtheRepeat%3A2%3Ablock1%3Aj_id44&lktp=' + getElementByIdCS('j_id0:newform:theRepeat:2:block1:j_id44_lktp').value,670,'1','&lksrch=' + escapeUTF(getElementByIdCS('j_id0:newform:theRepeat:2:block1:j_id44').value.substring(0, 80)))

Comment: @FrankZ by not working it means that the lookup doesn't popup when you click on the lookup button.

Comment: crop1645 i tried what u said but no luck , Born2BeMild yes its correct but how to resolve this error ?

Comment: I think that when the middle element in the collection is deleted the component id of the last one is decremented but the references to it in other parts of the page are not updated. So the id changes from id="j_id0:newform:theRepeat:2:block1:j_id44" to id="j_id0:newform:theRepeat:1:block1:j_id44"
but the onchange code stays with the original id. Thus when the lookup fires it cant find the item in the page.

My guess is that to fix this the div that this lot is in will need to be rerendered to get new ids and code propagated..